# scale floating divs at intervals

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to make a web page with floating `divs` with these requirements:

- the `divs` first stack horizontally and then stack vertically.
- the `divs` fill the screen at all times.
- at certain intervals the number of `divs` on a horizontal row changes

Example scenario: 
When the screen width is `100px`: a vertical stack of `divs` with size `100px x 100px`. When the screen width is `200px`: a stack with 2 `divs` of size `100px x 100px` at each row . A screen width between `100px and 200px`: the `divs` autoscale to fill the full screen and 2 `divs` remain on each row.

I've experimented trying to fulfil these requirements, but I haven't cracked the solution yet. This is what I have so far. The problem is mostly the scaling part.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.image {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


@media (max-width: 100px) {
.image {
   width:10%   
  }
}

@media (min-width:101px) and (max-width: 200px){
    .image {
   width:20%
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few changes, this might be what you are looking for, although a view of `100px` and `200px` it is a very small view.

#### Snippet

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.image {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}

@media (min-width: 101px) and (max-width: 200px) {
  .image {
    max-width: 49%
  }
}
@media (max-width: 100px) {
  .image  {
    float:none;
    max-width:100%
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: kittens like to hide in small spaces ;)